# Multiple templete same logic in angular 2

Tags: angular

In my angular app i have a component which implements two different layout for displaying the data.
1) masonary layout
2) list view.

So the content templete looks like this.

```
<div>
    <!--Layout one-->
    <div *ngIf="isGrid">
      <div *ngFor="let test of testData">
         <layout-one-template [data]="test"></layout-one-template>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--Layout one ends-->

<!--Layout two starts-->
   <div *ngIf="isList">
      <div *ngFor="let test of testData">
         <layout-two-template [data]="test"></layout-two-template>
      </div>
   </div>
<!--Layout two ends-->
</div>
```

Both layout are only different in presentation,both have the same functionalities.

I have created separate components for these layouts.
How i can use the same functions for both the components.
I don't want to keep the same functions and data in two different component.ts files.
I hope i have been able to put my question properly.
Is there a way that the templates remain in the component scope.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question layout-one-template and layout-two-template have same functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OOP inheritance.

You have a class BaseLayoutTemplate which is extended by layout-one-template and layout-two-template component.

For sample:

```
export class BaseLayoutTemplate {
  doSomething() {
     ....
  }
  protected doSomething2() {
     ....
  }
}

export class LayoutOneTemplateComponent extends BaseLayoutTemplate {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
  myFunctionInLayoutOneTemplate(){
    this.doSometing()
  }
}

export class LayoutTwoTemplateComponent extends BaseLayoutTemplate {
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
  myFunctionInLayoutTwoTemplate(){
    this.doSometing()
    this.doSometing2()
  }
}
```

`super()` is not required if you haven't arguments in BaseLayoutTemplate's constructor. If you have it, super takes the same argument in same order of the mother class's constructor

You can use protected before the method name if you want that the method is not accessible from view.

If a method of the BaseClass must do defined into extended class you can use abstract class or method: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use some funstions on testData, or some functions that returns values, just create new Class with there and import it in both components.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of ngif and when you are using angular 4 you can also use ifthen else, which precisely answer your requirement.

[Chek this post](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/52/Trying-out-the-New-Angular-4-If-Else-Conditionals)

you can also look at the documentation of angular that can help understand ifthenelse in angular 4

[Angular documentation of ngif then else](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)